How to propertly format "Δ" using MathML?
I'm using MathML embedded in HTML to put mathematical expressions in an HTML document. I'm having difficulty with properly formatting mathematical expressions containing "Δ". The MathML expressions
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mi mathvariant="normal">&Delta;</mi>
    <mi>x</mi>
  </mrow>
</math>

and
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mo>&Delta;</mo>
    <mi>x</mi>
  </mrow>
</math>

each yield "Δ " (i.e. with space between "Δ" and ""), while
<math>
  <mi>&Delta;x</mi>
</math>

yields "Δx" (i.e. "x" isn't italicized).
Is there a generally accepted way to properly format "Δ" using MathML?

Do you consider the delta character to be part of an identifier - or do you consider it an operator?

@Dai - Upon further thought, for my particular use case, Δ is being used as a parameter as opposed to Δ being an operator applied to the variable .

I tried using Δ instead of Δ, but that still resulted in space between "Δ" and "".

After some experimentation, it appears that MathML rendering puts space between a non-italic letter followed by an italic letter. Thus it puts space between a non-italic "Δ" that is followed by an italic "".

Another solution, the MathML expression
<math>
  <mi>&Delta;&#x1D465;</mi>
</math>

yields "Δ".
Note that &#x1D465; is an HTML entity for the "mathematical italic small x" character.

This answer has the disadvantage of reduced human readability of the MathML source--almost no one will know off the top of their head that &x1D465; means mathematical italic small x.

This answer considers Δ to be a 2-character identifier (as opposed to the operator Δ being applied to the identifier , which I address in another answer to this question).

The MathML expression
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mo lspace="0em" rspace="0em">&Delta;</mo>
    <mi>x</mi>
  </mrow>
</math>

yields "Δ".

This answer considers This answer considers Δ to be the operator Δ being applied to the identifier , (as opposed to a 2-character identifier, which I address in another answer to this question).
Note that lspace="0em" and rspace="0em" are needed because &Delta; isn't in the MathML operator dictionary.

Here's one more solution
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mtext>&Delta;</mtext>
    <mi>x</mi>
  </mrow>
</math>

also yields "Δ".
